# How does the FireBeetle ESP32 regulate to 3.3v? (schematic provided)

Tags: esp32, voltage

The [FireBeetle ESP32](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1590.html) advertises an input voltage of 3.3v-5v, with an operating voltage of 3.3v.

I tested this with an 18650 lithium-ion battery and can confirm this is true. For 3.3V < Vbat < 4.2V, there is a consistent ~3.295 volts at the 3V3 pin. For Vbat < 3.3V, 3V3 drops slightly under Vbat (approx. -.02V).

I found this odd because the onboard RT9080-33GJ5 regulator has a dropout of about 0.2V to 0.3V, so theoretically the output voltage should drop off steeply for Vbat < 3.6V.

Looking at the [schematic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DFRobot/Wiki/master/DFR0478/%5BDFR0478%5DFireBeetle%20Board-ESP32(V4.0)%E7%94%9F%E4%BA%A7%E6%A3%80%E6%9F%A5%E5%9B%BE.PDF), I was unable to figure out exactly how this board is able to regulate to 3.3 volts with essentially no dropout. Is it using some sort of buck converter that isn't mentioned in the schematic, or some other clever circuit?

Any help understanding would be much appreciated!

Comment: your question is off-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question - I didn't realize that dropout voltage essentially goes to 0 for this regulator when current consumption is low. Pretty neat for low current applications with the ESP32.